# Rendering django model validation error in template

Tags: python, django

I am building a web application on django. As part of this, I have created one html form like following:

```
 <form method="post" action="/voting/add_state/">{% csrf_token %}
     State name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="state_name"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

In models.py I have added unique constraint validation on name like following:

```
class State(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   vote_counted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So for duplicate name, it throws a unique constraint error which I would like to capture in the template. Can anyone please give any suggestion.

Comment: How are you saving the POST data? Can you post the relevant code.

Comment: @Selcuk, I'd imagine he hasn't modified anything from Django's default saving method.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim It does not look like that from the template.

Comment: Oh. You're right. I missed the action attribute. >.<

Comment: Thanks @all. I figured it out.

Comment: @joy did my answer help out?

Answer (score 0):

Django has  [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) processing built in. Django has "[Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/)", which automatically render the form for your model. If you pass it through the view and reference it in the context it will automatically generate the html for you, but if you would like more control over what is rendered in the template then you can reference the form attributes that Django Model Form produces.

I strongly suggest working within the framework Django provides to you for building forms; it provides a lot of boilerplate code for building, validating and abstracting forms and is especially competent for simple forms like these.

**Here is an example:**

models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  vote_counted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py

```
class StateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = State
    fields = (name,)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class StateForm(FormView):
    template_name = 'state_form.html'
    form_class = StateForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'
```

state_form.html (example of auto generated form)

```
{{ form }}
```

state_form.html (example of custom form)

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% for field in form %}
        <input type="{{ field.type }}" name='{{ field.name }}' class="submit" value="{{ field.value}}">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name='submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

References:

Django Forms: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/

Django Model Forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/

Django Generic Views:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView

Answer (score 0):

Create a form based on your model

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import State

class StateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('name',)
```

now use this form on your views

```
#views.py
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import StateForm

class MyView(FormView):

    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = StateForm
    success_url = '/my-url-to-redirect-after-submit/'
```

template.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Name 
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ form.name.errors }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form for `State` model and create the validator, so if the user try with a duplicate name, the form raise a message something like this:

```
models.py
class State(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   vote_counted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

forms.py
def unique_name(value):
    exist = State.objects.filter(name=value)
    if exist:
        raise ValidationError(u"A state with the name %s already exist" % value)

class StateForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label=('Name:'), validators=[unique_name])
```

Then you just need to render the `StateForm` in the template.